# How to start a browser with specific URL on a remote machine using Karma or other tool?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, karma-runner, e2e-testing, testcafe

For e2e tests, I use Testcafe that allows run tests on remote devices.
To start tests on remote devices I must enter a generated by Testcafe URL in a remote browser.
Can anybody suggest a solution when I can remotely start a browser and tell it to go to a particular URL?

Maybe someone who works with Karma can suggest a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which browser on which OS do you want to start?

Comment: It can be macOS or Windows with Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, TestCafe doesn't support this out of the box. But maybe the following ideas will help you:

- Start SSH or Telnet server on the remote machine. Then write a script that will start a browser via SSH/Telnet. The test url will be passed as the second argument. Then use `path` provider to start the script. Visit [this thread](https://testcafe-discuss.devexpress.com/t/launching-browser-in-virtual-x-mode/76) to know how to start browser via script with TestCafe.
- Implement a backend service that will be installed on the remote machine and will start browser by REST API or RPC, e.g. for node you can look at [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) (For REST), [dnode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dnode) (for RPC) and [testcafe-browser-tools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/testcafe-browser-tools)(for starting browsers). Then implement a [Browser Provider](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/extending-testcafe/browser-provider-plugin/) frontend that will proxy all Browser Provider API requests and send them you to your backend.